# Parameters not being passed up to main class

Tags: c#, parameters, constructor

I currently have a problem where my program should show parameters from each class onto the form, however the class lowest in the hierarchy isn't showing. For example; I want it to show "Charity Cyclist No. 1 riding a tricycle with 3 wheels and £300 sponsorship" but it's only showing "Charity Cyclist No. 1 riding a tricycle with 3 wheels".

Here is my Sponsorship class:

```
class Sponsorship : CharityCyclists
{
    private double fundsRaised;

    public double FundsRaised
    {
        get { return fundsRaised; }
        set { fundsRaised = value; }
    }

    public Sponsorship(String type, int number, String finished, int hours, int mins, int secs, string bicycle, int wheels, double fundsRaised) : base(type, number, finished, hours, mins, secs, bicycle, wheels, fundsRaised)
    {
        this.fundsRaised = fundsRaised;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString() + " and sponsorship amount: " + fundsRaised;
    }
}
```

Here is my CharityCyclists class:

```
class CharityCyclists : Cyclists
{

    private string bicycle;
    private int wheels;

    public string Bicycle
    {
        get { return bicycle; }
        set { bicycle = value; }
    }

    public int Wheels
    {
        get { return wheels; }
        set { wheels = value; }
    }


    public CharityCyclists(string type, int number, string finished, int hours, int mins, int secs, string bicycle, int wheels, double fundsRaised) : base(type, number, finished, hours, mins, secs)
    {
        this.bicycle = bicycle;
        this.wheels = wheels;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString() + " riding a " + bicycle + " with " + wheels + " wheels";
    }
}
```

and my Cyclists class:

```
    public static int NumFinished
    {
        get { return Cyclists.numFinished; }
        set { Cyclists.numFinished = value; }
    }

    public string Type
    {
        get { return type; }
        set { type = value; }
    }

    public int Number
    {
        get { return number; }
        set { number = value; }
    }

    public string Finished
    {
        get { return finished; }
        set { finished = value; }
    }

    public int Hours
    {
        get { return hours; }
        set { hours = value; }
    }

    public int Mins
    {
        get { return mins; }
        set { mins = value; }
    }

    public int Secs
    {
        get { return secs; }
        set { secs = value; }
    }

    public Cyclists(string type, int number, string finished, int hours, int mins, int secs)
    {
        this.type = type;
        this.number = number;
        this.finished = finished;
        this.hours = hours;
        this.mins = mins;
        this.secs = secs;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {

        return type + " No. " + number;
    }

    public Cyclists()
    {

    }
```

This is where they are added to the listbox on the form:

```
        Cyclists[] cyclistsList;
        cyclistsList = new Cyclists[2];

        cyclistsList[0] = new CharityCyclists("Novelty Charity Cyclist", 1, "Not Finished", 0, 0, 0, "Tricycle", 2, 300);
        cyclistsList[1] = new CompetitiveCyclists("Competitive Cyclist", 1, "Not Finished", 0, 0, 0, 25, 2);

        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CYCLISTS; i++)
        {
            lstCyclists.Items.Add(cyclistsList[i]);
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should remove the `fundsRaised` parameter from the `CharityCyclists` class constructor, because it is unused. You are probably creating an instance of `CharityCyclists` instead of `Sponsorship`.

Comment: Need to see the code creating and using the instance...

Comment: Show us the usage of the class, i.e where you do the `new` and the `ToString` calls.

Comment: They are just added via an array on the form_load, I've edited my post to show this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not creating Sponsorship instances at all. At this moment you are calling ToString() override of a CharityCyclist class, not Sponsorship because of this constructor call: `cyclistsList[0] = new CharityCyclists("Novelty Charity Cyclist", 1, "Not Finished", 0, 0, 0, "Tricycle", 2, 300);` You should modify your code like this:

```
Cyclists[] cyclistsList;
        cyclistsList = new Cyclists[2];

    cyclistsList[0] = new Sponsorship("Novelty Charity Cyclist", 1, "Not Finished", 0, 0, 0, "Tricycle", 2, 300);
    cyclistsList[1] = new CompetitiveCyclists("Competitive Cyclist", 1, "Not Finished", 0, 0, 0, 25, 2);

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CYCLISTS; i++)
    {
        lstCyclists.Items.Add(cyclistsList[i]);
    }
```

It is about polymorphism, you need to make an instance of the class which overridden method you would like to be called.